# LCD screen is black on Nikon FA

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, 35mm, old-cameras

When I look through the view finder of my Nikon FA, I am unable to see the LCD screen on the upper left of the view finder.

1. I've tried two sets of batteries. With both sets of batteries, the shutter fires when in automatic mode. This would lead me to believe the batteries are working fine.
2. I've tried looking through the view finder in all 4 modes with no luck.

Supposedly the LCD screen was working before the camera was shipped to me.

Any idea what might be going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to use it in low ambient light, or is sufficient light coming through the lens? I ask because according to WP, "Unfortunately, the LCD could not be illuminated in low ambient light situations"

Comment: I was trying to use it in the sunny outdoors.

Answer (score 1):

Hope your face or fingers doesn't cover the light sensor that activates the LCD, while looking through the VF. If so, the LCD won't trigger.